# NOTIFYURL not noticed during paypal call?

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I've set up a PayPal Express Checkout, and I'm at the final stage with putting in an IPN listener, but when I put the IPN url in the DoExpressCheckoutPayment call, it doesn't read it, it just calls on the IPN specified in my Profile?

I'm using Sandbox at the moment, if that makes a difference, it's running through cURL and my code for the IPN url call is `&NOTIFYURL=http://www.example.com/ipn.php`

Can anyone tell me what I've done wrong? Has this happened before?

Comment: "NOTIFYURL is deprecated since version 63.0. Use PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NOTIFYURL instead. "

Comment: @Dagon, thanks, that fixed it straight away :) I don't know why it wasn't listed anywhere! Hard bugger to come across!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

as this page says: https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_r_GetExpressCheckoutDetails

"NOTIFYURL is deprecated since version 63.0. Use PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NOTIFYURL instead. "