# php - PayPal IPN Not Working (on Sandbox)

Tags: php, mysql, paypal, sandbox, paypal-ipn

**UPDATE: I've even tried having the whole PHP script just be a single line that emails me when the script is viewed, and it still doesn't email me.**

I've tried everything, or so I feel like. I have the script set up (very basic just so I can learn how to use it) to insert a row based upon the IPN response (completed, invalid, etc.)

However, it does not appear to be doing anything.

I've tried using the sandbox's built in IPN tester, and it does not do anything. I've tried using a Sandbox-based donator button with "notify_url" as a hidden input type, and it does not do anything.

The only time a row is actually inserted, is when I visit the file directly over my browser (the IPN file, of course). In that case, it inserts a row saying it was an invalid payment.

What in the dickens am I doing wrong or is PayPal's sandbox temporarily screwed up?

```
<?php
require("../functions.php");
sql();

// read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
$req = 'cmd=' . urlencode('_notify-validate');

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
    $req .= "&$key=$value";
}


$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Host: www.paypal.com'));
$res = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);


// assign posted variables to local variables
$item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
$item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
$payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
$payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
$payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
$txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
$receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
$payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];


if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
    // check the payment_status is Completed
    // check that txn_id has not been previously processed
    // check that receiver_email is your Primary PayPal email
    // check that payment_amount/payment_currency are correct
    // process payment
    if($payment_status == "Completed") {
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO donators (username)
VALUES ('completed')");
    } else {
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO donators (username)
        VALUES ('wrong payment status')");
    }

}
else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO donators (username)
    VALUES ('invalid')");
}
?>
```

Donator form:

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="QJUZ2AGANUWYS">
<input name="notify_url" value="http://mysite.com/libs/paypal/ipn.php" type="hidden">
<input type="image" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_donateCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

Comment: Ensure you're using up-to-date information. I went through this same process, following the instructions on the PayPal website, only to find they're out of date. I believe your `notify_url` is actually incorrect, that was my issue. I'll report back if I can find the information I used to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the invalid payment could be coming from the fact you were using a credit card or a credit card simulation by a sandbox account.
Throw away the condition `if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {` and you'll be ok.

i do not know the sandbox's built in IPN tester, sorry, probably someone here will help you on that point.

Answer (score 0):

> as this page says:
>   https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_r_GetExpressCheckoutDetails
>
> "NOTIFYURL is deprecated since version 63.0. Use
>   PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NOTIFYURL instead. "

[Link to post here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8146303/563460)

Also, as a Code Injection point, do **not** put your IPN address in your HTML code. Anyone can view it, and as such know the location of the file. For safety purposes, put it inside your background PHP script, inside you're `Paypal functions` file, inside the function call `ConfirmPayment`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried trimming $res?

```
strcmp(trim($res), "VERIFIED")
```

instead of

```
strcmp($res, "VERIFIED")
```

That's what finally got it working for me...